# Using Project Expressions in Dynamo DB

Tags: aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-cli, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have a DynamoDB table and I am trying to just get one column from the table. More specifically I just want distinct values from a column.

I am using AWS Amplify and have setup an API to query the DynamoDB table.

The get method in the API is as follows.
where

1. tableName - is a variable that contains the name of the table.
2. Listing_Location is the column I want to retrieve from the table.

```
app.get(path, function (req, res) {

  if (userIdPresent) {
    req.body['userId'] = req.apiGateway.event.requestContext.identity.cognitoIdentityId || UNAUTH;
  }

  var queryItemParams = {
    TableName: tableName,
    ProjectionExpression: "#listing_location",
    ExpressionAttributeNames = { 
      '#listing_location': 'Listing_Location'
    }
  };

  dynamodb.scan(queryItemParams, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.statusCode = 500;
      res.json({ error: 'Could not fetch listing locations : ' + err });
    } else {
      res.json(data.Items);
    }
  });
});
```

from the front end React application I make the following get request, where
apiName is the variable which has the API name.
path is the api endpoint to make the get request.
and I am importing API like this

```
import { Amplify, API } from 'aws-amplify';
```

```
  getAllLocations = () => {
    console.log("in getAllLocations");
    API.get(apiName, path).then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    });
  }
```

Can you help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cannot believe I made this mistake

```
ExpressionAttributeNames = {
```

should

```
ExpressionAttributeNames : {
```